# How to access Google Cloud Storage from Firebase functions on the server

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I want to upload some data to Google Cloud Storage and then run a Firebase Function on the server to process the data.

My reason for this is that the data (representing information I want to import into Firestore) could be quite large – maybe 50MB. I could easily have data that represents 30,000 documents. I don't want to process the data on my local machine because it would possibly take several hours.

My problem is I can't find a way to access Cloud Storage from the server itself. I can easily download and upload files between local and server. I've spent the last several hours reading through the docs but everything seems to be based on accessing Cloud Storage from a local instance.

Comment: There are lots of SDKs for various languages that you can use to work with Cloud Storage in backend code.  Are you just having problems finding those?

Comment: Yes @DougStevenson, I guess there are just too many SDKs and it's quite confusing. I've been following your videos on "Getting started with Cloud Functions" and I have no problems accessing Cloud Firestore. I just can't see what I would have to do to access Cloud Storage. Right at the moment I just want to post to a HTTP end point and then within that function I want to grab hold of a file from Cloud Storage. I just can't see how to do that.

Comment: Which [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin) are you using?

Comment: To be clear, I am using Cloud Functions and when I say “server” I mean Google Cloud. In this scenario I thought I had to use the Node SDK. I found this tutorial https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-cloud-functions/#10 but it only shows how to respond to Cloud Storage events.

Comment: There is a node SDK for Cloud Functions.  You can also use the Firebase Admin SDK, which wraps the Cloud node SDK.  These are easy to find.

Comment: OK, I have been using the node SDK for Cloud Functions. I still can't see anyway from there where I can go and grab a document from Storage. I found this in the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_storage_. I hope you can understand that page because I can't. And I found this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.storage which makes no more sense to me than the first one. I have been using Cloud Functions for a while now and have written some pretty extensive stuff. But Storage has got me stumped

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger Cloud Functions to run when a change is made in Cloud Storage. Docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage). The file uploaded or changed is already included in the metadata, so you don't need to "access storage" per se. From the example:

```
/**
 * Generic background Cloud Function to be triggered by Cloud Storage.
 *
 * @param {object} data The event payload.
 * @param {object} context The event metadata.
 */
exports.helloGCSGeneric = (data, context) => {
  const file = data;
  console.log(`  Event ${context.eventId}`);
  console.log(`  Event Type: ${context.eventType}`);
  console.log(`  Bucket: ${file.bucket}`);
  console.log(`  File: ${file.name}`);
  console.log(`  Metageneration: ${file.metageneration}`);
  console.log(`  Created: ${file.timeCreated}`);
  console.log(`  Updated: ${file.updated}`);
};
```

If you want direct access to Storage from within the function (if for example you want to write back to Storage with new/altered data), you use the Storage SDKs. Examples for all supported languages are [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries). Example from the docs:

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();
// Creates a client from a Google service account key.
// const storage = new Storage({keyFilename: "key.json"});

/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment these variables before running the sample.
 */
// const bucketName = 'bucket-name';

async function createBucket() {
  // Creates the new bucket
  await storage.createBucket(bucketName);
  console.log(`Bucket ${bucketName} created.`);
}

createBucket();
```

**A very important caveat!** Cloud Functions has a maximum execution time of about 60 seconds ([limits doc](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas)). So long running processes up to 15 minutes should utilize [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/) instead. Longer running processes should run in an environment like [App Engine](https://www.google.com/aclk?sa=l&ai=DChcSEwjZnJHm85nmAhXeH60GHf5DC2sYABAAGgJwdg&sig=AOD64_3TvUZz3Xz6B5KteRtt4bjSrafWrw&q=&ved=2ahUKEwj_7Ybm85nmAhV_JzQIHTAMAegQ0Qx6BAgOEAE&adurl=) (which you could kick off from your function and delegate the work to the App Engine instance).

Comment: Kato, what do you mean "maximum execution time of about 60 seconds" isn't 9 minutes, 60 seconds is the default.